# Could not open input file: C:\Users\MyUsername

Tags: php, laravel, web, command-line

When trying to install a new laravel project
I type in this code on my cmd

```
    laravel new sitename
```

and then the cmd shows this error:

Could not open input file: `C:\Users\Leon`

Comment: We're going to need some more information to be helpful. What steps have you done already? What installation tutorial are you following?

Comment: What is the version of `laravel` you are using?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new laravel project use this in your cmd :

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 4.2.*
```